# how to sum rows whose values are equal to a random variable in excel 2010

Tags: excel

I want to want to sum the rows of an excel sheet whose value are equal to some random value.
for example:

```
A     B
12    3
12    5
10    6
13    7
13    2
13    2
...
```

for example I want to sum all the B whose A are equal. that is sum all the B whose A are 12, then 10 etc.. using the function sumif() I am not able to dynamically pass the value of A.. does any one has an Idea

Comment: You could use a pivot table for this.

Comment: what is the exact expression you used in sumif ? (intrigued by your "not able to dynamically pass the value of A")

Comment: thank you for your answer, but actually the main proble is that  the range is also random

Comment: @Thomas basically this is how it looks like sumif($A$1:$A$2;"="&A1;$B1:$B2)

Comment: `=SUMIF($A:$B,A3,$B:$B)` or Create the Pivot table by Selecting Range `Sheet1!$A:$B` then you can refresh the pivot table if you add the data into COLUMN A and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these two options:

```
Use a sumif with the range like this:

To get the sum use formula
=SUMIF(A5:A10,B1,B5:B10)

Here A5:A10 is criteria range. B1 is variable criteria cell, and B5:B10 is sum range.


Use a sumif with a table.
=SUMIF(Table2[A],B1,Table2[B])
Here Table2[A](Tablename[Columnname]) is criteria range, B1 is variable criteria cell, and Table2[B] is column used for sum.
```

[Find an example in this excel document.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9sZm9GYZvnXYUtIUzlhQklXejQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome, its my pleasure :)